# preference BackupWebStorage reset to default after cordova build

Tags: cordova, preference

This is my first cordova-based iOS app (using cordova 4.1.2).

I want to deactivate web storage being backed up to the cloud by setting 
`<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />` in `/Staging/config.xml`.

However, after doing a `cordova build` the preference is reset to its default value "cloud".

So I tried setting the preference in the `config.xml` file that is located in the project root instead. But this just adds a second BackupWebStorage preference (correctly set to "none") but does not replace the generated preference in `/Staging/config.xml` which is still set to "cloud". So two BackupWebStorage preference in the same file - not good.

After searching through the web I found out that `file.setMetadata` with `com.apple.MobileBackup` set to 1 deactivates cloud backup for each individual file it is called for. Maybe this is the way to go.

But still, I'd like to know, if there is a persistent way to set BackupWebStorage preference to "none" so that it will not be reset to "cloud" after a rebuild.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed that relate to cloud storage? If so, the plugin could be adding that setting and then you would need to check the `plugin.xml` file for that plugin and make the change there

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I'm only using those standard cordova plugins (device, camera, media-capture, file, file-transfer, and console).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BackupWebStorage is a platform-specific preference so in your root config.xml it needs to be specified within the platform tag in order to be placed into the right platform-specific config.xml when doing a cordova build.

**Example:** 
Put this into the root config.xml

```
<platform name="ios"> 
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" /> 
</platform>
```

to make this the actual BackupWebStorage preference setting within the ios config.xml.

See https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html (bottom of page)